# how do I return the sum of all of the costs?

Tags: python

So, I've been doing code academy for a while. I have an assignment that says I need to return the sum of the costs of my previous functions. How do I do that because this way isn't working? And how do I avoid running into this problem in the future?

```
def hotel_cost(nights)
    nights = raw_input("How many nights are you staying? ")
    if nights == 0:
            return 0
    elif nights > 0:
        return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        cost = 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        cost = 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        cost = 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        cost = 475
    return cost

def rental_car_cost(days):
    days = nights
    cost = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost -= 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return  rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(cost) + hotel_cost(days)
```

I get this error:

```
hotel_cost(1) raised an error:
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the line nights = raw_input(...) in the code? The way the code is written implies you want to pass the number of nights to the function hotel_cost. But you're overwriting the passed in nights value with a string from the raw_input call

Comment: You should also provide the full error details as these tell us what line the error occurs on.

Comment: Also you can use `input()`

Comment: Nice tags... [tag:python-2.7] **and** [tag:python-3.x] :)

Comment: If something applies to python-27 and python-3.x, just tag it with [tag:python] Version specific tags are only for _specific functionality_ that doesn't apply to other versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
nights = raw_input("How many nights are you staying? ")
```

`raw_input` returns a string, you need to convert it to an integer. Use `int(nights)`.

[int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) the docs

Comment: `10` is already the default. You don't need to provide it explicitly.

Comment: @user2357112 Ta, I was thinking of another language.

Comment: I tried that solution and it didn't work. The line of code looks like:

nights = int(raw_input("How many nights are you staying? "))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nights = input("How many nights are you staying? ")
```

`input()` returns an int

I think it will be better if you avoid getting user input within a function, in this particular case you can collect all the info in an external function, for instance:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    days = input('Something..')
    nights = input('Something...')
    city = raw_input('Something...')
    # do whatever you want with data
    print  plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(nights)
```

Don't know the way you are using this example...

You cand read about  [input()](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only expecting integers as the input, change the following line:

```
nights = raw_input("How many nights are you staying? ")
```

To:

```
nights = int(raw_input("How many nights are you staying? "))
```

This will fix the error by casting `int()` to your `raw_input()`, which returns a string.

```
>>> x = raw_input()
98
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> x = int(raw_input())
23
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```